# windows 10 L2TP/Ipsec VPN with synology NAS not working

Tags: networking, vpn, nas

I am using a Synology NAS that has an L2TP/IPsec VPN server running. The NAS is located in a network behind a FritzBox router, and I am in another network that is also established behind a FritzBox router. From here, I can connect to the VPN via Debian and Android, but not from a Surface Pro 4 (up-to-date).

How do I fix the inaccessibility on the Surface Pro 4?

- **Added:** `AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule` with `DWORD` value `2`: 
   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent`
- **Services Running:**  
   `IPsec Policy Agent` & `IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Module`
- **Network Adapter:** [image: adapter settings]

I verified the credentials several times (username, domain, password, preconfigured key, etc.), but I still receive this error, with no error code I can follow:

```
The network connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be established
because the remote server is not responding.

This could be because one of the network devices (e.g. firewalls, NAT, routers, etc.)
between your computer and the remote server is not configured to allow VPN connections.

Please contact your Administrator or your service provider to determine which device may 
be causing the problem
```

---

I have tried the following, with none resolving the issue:

- Device Manager > Network adapters > Delete all WAN Miniports > Action > Scan for hardware changes
- Disabled `Xbox Live-Networkservice` (not running)
- Restarted `DHCP-Client`, but permission denied with code `4`, so I could not restart. 
   Trying to fix this permission issue did not work *(more permissions in the registry and adding some extra users to the Admin group like System and so on)*, so I tried other things.

What am I missing? Why is this setup working on several Windows 10 computers, but not on this one Surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it accidentally.
Windows has problems when there is a manual DNS configured on the network adapter.

So the following fixed it for me:
`Win + R` -> `ncpa.cpl` -> right click on the network adapter that is used for the internet connection (wifi or lan) -> settings -> (in my case additionally disabling IPv6) -> click on `IPv4` -> settings -> then `DNS-Serveraddress automatically` and not manually

If there are still problems, temporary disable the adapter `Npcap Loopback Adapter` if present.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows 10 Version matches 1709, try uninstalling Update [KB4457142](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4457142/windows-10-update-kb4457142).

I've had a similar Problem with IKEv2 yesterday and resolved it by temporary uninstalling the Update.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I am using 1803. And uninstalling also had no effect. But worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar problems with VPN/IKEv2 and KB4457142 on version 1709. Removing KB4457142 fixes the problem. Version 1803 with the equalent KB4457128 works fine with VPN/IKEv2

Comment: also no effect.